# Can't issue http requests from Android to Django webserver with Apache

Tags: java, android, django, apache, http

I'm trying to issue a post request to my django webserver (which behaves correctly when accessed via browser)

my post code:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://23.23.237.174/save-item");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_email", WeShouldActivity.ACCOUNT_NAME));
        for (Field f : mData.keySet()) {
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(f.getName(), mData.get(f)));
        }
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        Log.v("GETREFERRALSSERVICE", "backing up items");

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.v("GETREFERRALSSERVICE", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.v("GETREFERRALSSERVICE", e.getMessage());
    }
```

my complete error in apache2/access.log (nothing shows up in error.log)

```
174.253.199.12 - - [16/May/2012:03:25:15 +0000] "POST /save-item HTTP/1.1" 500 53055 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)"
```

Does anyone have any idea what this might be/how to fix?

NOTE: this IS an error. The request is not getting through to my view, where it does with the exact same url in a browser. I'm printing out the request first thing in my view and nothing shows up in error.log

Comment: Add yourself to [`ADMINS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admins) in your `settings.py` and set up [`EMAIL_HOST`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#email-host) and related `EMAIL_*` settings. Send the request again and check your email for the traceback, and update your question with the traceback.

Comment: the docs make it sound like I don't *need* to set EMAIL_HOST, etc. Do I? If so, what are appropriate values? I added myself to ADMINS but haven't gotten an email about the error.

Comment: set it to the outbound email server that your system uses. You most likely also need `EMAIL_HOST_USER` and `EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD` as most email servers won't deliver without authentication.

Comment: I don't have an email server set up... is that difficult? If not, can you point me to instructions on it?

Answer (score 1):

'Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)' is just the Android user agent string, not an error message. Something is wrong on the server side, you should try to debug it by adding logging, etc. Does the server side require authentication? If so, you might be missing a session cookie, etc.

BTW, since it seems you are adding more than two items, there is really no point in using new `ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2)` just use the default constructor.

Comment: So it would seem from the 500 status code. The point is that the title of this post is not exactly descriptive, since 'Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)' is not an _error message_.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();    
client.getParams().setBooleanParameter("http.protocol.expect-continue", false);
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: Hah, this was a class project long dead. but I appreciate the info. One of my eventual goals is to revive it and turn it into something better, so if I ever do I'll try this.